# Add record to database with C#/MVC/Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a database table of Golf Courses and their respective par value.  I am trying to add a row for a new Golf Course to the table.  The table has 3 columns `ID`, `CourseName`, and `Par`.

When attempting to add a row the code sets a value for only `CourseName` and `Par` because `ID` is an identity field.

When I click my `New Course` button, the behavior is wrong -- the code grabs the first row from the table and edits its instead of creating a new row.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using GolfScore.Data;

namespace GolfScore.Business
{
public class CourseManager
{
    public static void AddCourse(string Name, int Par)
    {
        using (DBContext context = new DBContext())
        {
            Course j = context.Courses.Create();

            context.Courses.Add(j);
            context.SaveChanges();

        }
    }

    public static void EditCourse(int? id, string Name, int Par)
    {
        using (DBContext context = new DBContext())
        {

            Course t = context.Courses.Where(c => c.CourseId ==  id).FirstOrDefault();
            t.CourseName = Name;
            t.Par = Par;
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    public static Course GetCourse(int? id)
    {
        if (id.HasValue) { 
            using (DBContext context = new DBContext())
            {
                return context.Courses.Where(c => c.CourseId == id.Value).FirstOrDefault();
            }
        }

        else
        {
            using (DBContext context = new DBContext())
            {
                return context.Courses.FirstOrDefault();
            }
        }

    }

    public static IList<Course> GetAllCourses()
    {
        using(DBContext context = new DBContext())
        {
            return context.Courses.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

}

**CourseController**

```
using GolfScore.Business;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using GolfScore.Web.Models;

namespace GolfScore.Web.Controllers
{
    public class CourseController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Course
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(CourseManager.GetAllCourses());
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public PartialViewResult AddEdit(int? id)
        {
            return PartialView("_AddEditCourse", CourseManager.GetCourse(id));
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Save(Course c)
        {
            if (c.Id.HasValue)
            {
                CourseManager.EditCourse(c.Id, c.Name, c.Par);
            }
            else
            {
                CourseManager.AddCourse(c.Name, c.Par);
            }
            return Json(new
            {
                Success = true
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**Javascript**

```
var Course = function (dialogSelector, addUrl, saveUrl) {
    self = this;
    self.dialogElement = dialogSelector;
    self.addAJAXUrl = addUrl;
    self.saveAJAXUrl = saveUrl;
    self.dialog = null;

    self.Initialize = function () {
        self.dialog = $(self.dialogElement).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 400,
            width: 350,
            modal: true,
            buttons: [
                {
                    text: "Save",
                    click: function () {
                        var jsonObject = {
                            "Id": parseInt($("#CourseId").val()),
                            "Name": $("#CourseName").val(),
                            "Par": parseInt($("#Par").val())
                        };

                        $.ajax({
                            url: self.saveAJAXUrl,
                            type: "POST",
                            contentType: "application/json",
                            dataType: "json",
                            data: JSON.stringify(jsonObject),
                            success: function () {
                                self.dialog.dialog("close");
                                location.reload();
                            },
                            error: function (a, b, c) {
                                alert("stupid");
                            }
                        })
                    }
                },
                {
                    text: "Cancel",
                    click: function (){
                        self.dialog.dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            ],
            close: function () {
                self.dialog.dialog("close");
            }
        });

        $(".newBtn").on("click", function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: self.addAJAXUrl,
                type: "GET",
                success: function (data) {
                    $(self.dialogElement).html(data);
                    self.dialog.dialog("option", "title", "New Course");
                    self.dialog.dialog("open");
                },
                error: function (a, b, c) {
                    alert("Error.");
                }
            })
        });

        $(".editBtn").on("click", function (e) {
            $.ajax({
                url: self.addAJAXUrl + "?Id=" + $(e.target).attr("data-course-id"),
                type: "GET",
                success: function (data) {
                    $(self.dialogElement).html(data);
                    self.dialog.dialog("option", "title", "Edit Course");
                    self.dialog.dialog("open");
                },
                error: function (a, b, c) {
                    alert("Error.");
                }
            })
        });
    };
}
```

If you need anything else, let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Sorry, here is the course class.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace GolfScore.Web.Models
{
    [Serializable()]
    public class Course
    {
        public int? Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Par { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to show the source for your `Course` class as well...

Comment: your `GetCourse` method is not returning the first element instead of a new element

Comment: you're not actually doing anything with the name or par in your code

Answer (score 0):

```
        [HttpGet]
        public PartialViewResult AddEdit(int? id)
        {
            return PartialView("_AddEditCourse", CourseManager.GetCourse(id));
        }
```

this action you need to changed like this:

```
 [HttpGet]
 public PartialViewResult AddEdit(int? id)
{

   if(id.HasValue)
       return PartialView("_AddEditCourse", CourseManager.GetCourse(id));

   return PartialView("_AddEditCourse",new Course())
 }
```

and the method GetCourse must return only the Course if id has value.

On save, you need to check if id==0, because if is a new record, you will have id=0, otherwse id>0.

Edit:

your method to get a course must be like this:

```
public static Course GetCourse(int id){
 using (DBContext context = new DBContext())
            {
                return context.Courses.Find(id);
            }
}
```

to see why you get error I need you to post the razor view.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  I made the changes you suggested and now it is throwing an error when I click the Add Course button.  On the GetCourse method, I set it to return null if there is no course ID.  On the save, if there is no ID, it just returns a course name and par because the ID field should auto-generate.  At least I think.  I am pretty new to this and had someone helping me get it started.

Comment: What kind of error do you get? Your `AddCourse` method is not ok, you are adding an empty course. You need to give to the new object the values for name and par.

Comment: I don't know.  I just get a popup that says localhost:73293  error.  Nothing more than that.  I finally see what you are talking about with the AddCourse method and have fixed that.

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me on this!!!  I reverted the first change we made and it started working.  I think the changes we made after that fixed the issue.  I went back on the AddEdit method and it is working.